# Docker Setup, cannot clone the repository because container name already taken

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am really new to Docker and am trying to set it up on my laptop. I am on the "Getting Started" project and am trying to clone the repository, but when I run the code it says `Error: No such container:path: repo:/git/getting-started/`

It also says `Error response from daemon: Conflict.T The container name "/repo" is already in use by container "23b79....."`

I tried to use File Explorer to find a folder named "repo" but could not find anything. I am also not sure how to search for that container since it just gives me a large string.

[Here is a screenshot of what it shows on Docker for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0gXz.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Docker containers won't show up on your filesystem but instead in Docker Desktop or through `docker ps`. To fix the conflict error, you can try running `docker system prune -f` to remove old containers that are no longer running. See docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) for more about this command. Your `docker cp` command won't work until you have a container named `repo` actually running.

Answer (score 1):

This failure can happen when a container with the same name is no longer running. Your second command `docker cp repo:/git/getting-started/ .` failed because a container `repo` was not created properly in the previous step.

You can check what containers are running on the Docker Desktop `Containers/Apps` page. Below shows the container named `csci104` and tagged from the repo `usccsci104/docker:20.04` is running:

[image: Docker Desktop Containers and Apps Page Screenshot]

Or you can check running containers with the `docker ps` command, [docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).

I would recommend you try to clear unused containers with [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) command or explicitly remove the `repo` container so you can try again:

```
# this will clear all unused containers you have created
docker system prune -f

# this will remove the /repo container causing docker run command to fail
docker rm -f repo
```

Then, retry running the `docker run` command and if this succeeds, retry the `docker cp` command.